# Is there a way to access resolved state dependencies besides injecting them into the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to access resolved data from a service or directive to do some general operations across the whole application.

The only way to I seem to be able to access resolved data is injecting it into the controller.

This is the test data I setup:

```
resolve: {
    test: function() {
         console.log("resolving");
        return 5+2;
    }
}
```

I have tried this in my controller just to see what happens, but it doesn't work:

```
$injector.invoke(function(test) {
    console.log("injected", test);
    $scope.test = test;
});
```

I get:

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testProvider <- test
```

So it seems that resolved data is passed as locals to the invoke function on the state controller.

I also found out that I can access the resolve object from the state:

```
$state.current.resolve
```

But this is the raw resolve object without the resolved data. I could invoke those functions to resolve the data, but I would be resolving dependencies all over again. If there were any requests on the resolve object they would be called twice.

I just need to access the resolved values just like I would access data attributes or the $state.params.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

It's possible to access all the resolved data through the $state.$current object:

```
$state.$current.locals.globals
```

Comment: Gotta love the naming of `locals.globals`. This is what I came to, too... would be nice to have someone from the angular-ui-router team respond if this is the correct way to get the values.

Comment: Since we are not using any variable prefixed with $$, which stands for "totally private and you shouldn't rely on this for compatibility", I guess it's ok to access it this way. Maybe there is a cleaner or more elegant way to do it. But I think it's safe to think this ok.

Comment: @jens Have you found a cleaner way to handle this ? No mention of this in ui-router official documentation.

Comment: @Marc No, it seems this is the way to do it for now.